# SQL Server, self referencing foreign compound key

Tags: sql, constraints

I have a table with columns task_id (pk), client_id, parent_task_id, title.  In other words, tasks are owned by clients, and some tasks have child tasks.

For example, client 7 may have a task "wash the car," with child tasks "vacuum carpet" and "wipe dashboard."

I want a constraint so that a task and its children are always owned by the same client.

Through a bit of experimentation, to do this, I created a self-referencing foreign key (client_id, parent_task_id) referencing (client_id, task_id).  At first I received an error (There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table that match the referencing column list in the foreign key.)  So I added a unique key for columns task_id, client_id.  Now it seems to work.

I am wondering if this is the best solution (or at least reasonable one) to enforce this constraint.  Any thoughts would be appreciated.  Thanks much!

Comment: Do you have the option of re-designing the tables, or do you have an existing application/reporting where you have to keep the current structure?

Comment: yes, I am still laying out the schema

Answer (score 1):

A 'parent' record would not need a [parent_task_id]

```
TASK ID | CLIENT ID | PARENT TASK ID | TITLE
1       | 7         | NULL           | wash the car
```

(To find all of your parent records, `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE [parent_task_id] is null`)

A 'child' record would need a [parent_task_id], but not a [client_id] (because, as you stipulate, a child has the same client as it's parent).

```
TASK ID | CLIENT ID | PARENT TASK ID | TITLE
2       | NULL      | 1              | vacuum carpent
3       | NULL      | 1              | wipe dashboard
```

In this way, your self-referencing foreign key is all the constraint you need.  No constraint / rule concerning [client_id] on child records is necessary, because all [client_id] values on child records will be ignored, in favor of the [client_id] on the parent record.

For example, if you want to know what the [client_id] is for a child record:

```
SELECT
   c.task_id,
   p.client_id,
   c.title
FROM
   table p --parent
   INNER JOIN table c --child
   ON p.task_id = c.parent_task_id
```

***UPDATE***
(How to query for the client ID of a grand-child)

```
--Create and populate your table (using a table var in this sample)
DECLARE @table table (task_id int, client_id int, parent_task_id int, title varchar(50))
INSERT INTO @table VALUES (1,7,NULL,'wash the car')
INSERT INTO @table VALUES (2,NULL,1,'vacuum carpet')
INSERT INTO @table VALUES (3,NULL,1,'wipe dashboard')
INSERT INTO @table VALUES (4,NULL,2,'Step 1: plug-in the vacuum')
INSERT INTO @table VALUES (5,NULL,2,'Step 2: turn-on the vacuum')
INSERT INTO @table VALUES (6,NULL,2,'Step 3: use the vacuum')
INSERT INTO @table VALUES (7,NULL,2,'Step 4: turn-off the vacuum')
INSERT INTO @table VALUES (8,NULL,2,'Step 5: empty the vacuum')
INSERT INTO @table VALUES (9,NULL,2,'Step 6: put-away the vacuum')
INSERT INTO @table VALUES (10,NULL,3,'Step 1: spray cleaner on the rag')
INSERT INTO @table VALUES (11,NULL,3,'Step 2: use the rag')
INSERT INTO @table VALUES (12,NULL,3,'Step 3: put-away the cleaner')
INSERT INTO @table VALUES (13,NULL,3,'Step 4: toss the rag in the laundry bin')

--Determine which grandchild you want the client_id for
DECLARE @task_id int
SET @task_id = 8 -- grandchild's ID to use to find client_id

--Create your CTE (this is the recursive part)
;WITH myList (task_id, client_id, parent_task_id, title)
AS
(
    SELECT a.task_id, a.client_id, a.parent_task_id, a.title
    FROM @table a
    WHERE a.task_id = @task_id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT a.task_id, a.client_id, a.parent_task_id, a.title
    FROM @table a
    INNER JOIN myList m
    ON a.task_id = m.parent_task_id
)

--Query your CTE
SELECT task_id, client_id, title FROM myList WHERE client_id is not null
```

In this example, I used a granchild's task_id (8 -- 'empty the vacuum') to find it's highest-level parent, which holds the client_id.

You can remove the WHERE clause from the last step if you want to see each parent, parent's parent, and so on up to the first-parent's record.

Comment: This would take care of consistency, but for grandchildren, etc. determining the client_id seems difficult.

Comment: @user3536970 -- It's not difficult; if you're going for more than 2 levels (grandchild, great-grandchild, etc.), then you'll need to use recursion.  See my updated answer for one way to do that.